# Laravel 4.2 PHPUnit testing all routes

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Hi I am busy editing and changing a test class to work with laravel 4.2 at the moment, I've made changes for the models currently however it is constantly throwing an exception that AllRoutesTest::withoutEvents() is an undefined method. Is there something that I am missing?

```
<?php

class AllRoutesTest extends TestCase
{
protected $admin;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->admin = User::find(1);
}

/**
 * test all route
 *
 * @group route
 */

public function testAllRoute()
{
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $this->withoutEvents();
    $blacklist = [
        'url/that/not/tested',
    ];
    $dynamicReg = "/{\\S*}/"; //used for omitting dynamic urls that have {} in uri
    $this->be($this->admin);
    foreach ($routeCollection as $route) {
        if (!preg_match($dynamicReg, $route->getUri()) &&
            in_array('GET', $route->getMethods()) &&
            !in_array($route->getUri(), $blacklist)
        ) {
            $start = $this->microtimeFloat();
            fwrite(STDERR, print_r('test ' . $route->getUri() . "\n", true));
            $response = $this->call('GET', $route->getUri());
            $end   = $this->microtimeFloat();
            $temps = round($end - $start, 3);
            fwrite(STDERR, print_r('time: ' . $temps . "\n", true));
            $this->assertLessThan(15, $temps, "too long time for " . $route->getUri());
            $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode(), $route->getUri() . "failed to load");

        }

    }
}

public function microtimeFloat()
{
    list($usec, $asec) = explode(" ", microtime());

    return ((float) $usec + (float) $asec);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you open up the TestCase class and see the withoutEvents() method?

Comment: Just checked and it's not there, how would I disable events for the class so I can check all routes within my laravel app? Thought the class existed already for some reason :(

Comment: Is the testcase class not there or is the method not there. And what events are you trying to disable?

Comment: The TestCase class exists and all I want to test are the get and post methods, there are form submissions, registration, login and social authentication as well as links to our companies social media pages.

Comment: There are other developers working on the project so I don't know what extra events they might add as I might only discuss and have meetings with them 1-2 times a month currently. All I want is to ensure that all POST and GET routes are functioning correctly when running the tests.